# Build both distributive and NPM package from the same source

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack, gulp, package

I often make small open source tools and I don't want to limit my users. My packages are usually just one function, so this is what I want my users to get:

1. A JS file that they can add via the `src` in the `script` tag. That script should add my function so they can call it in a script below. Useful for users who don't want to use a package manager at all:

```
<script src="https://amazingCDN.com/isEven.js"></script>
<script>
  isEven()
</script>
```

2. A JS file that can be published as a package, so users who use NPM can just type `npm install isEven` and then import my package.

Both JS files should be built from the same source. Let's say my source only contains a named function that should be added to the `window` and should be importable if I use Webpack. Let's say I will publish a package myself and I only want my building pipeline to generate two JS files from my source. What about CDN let's say I use jsDelivr and it can retrieve my JS file from Github and minify it so I don't care about minifying my file myself.

I tried writing my code as a module and using Browserify with the standalone flag. It actually works with CommonJS modules, but to make it work with ES modules I have to use esmify, and it just returns an object with the `default` key, so I can't call it like `foo()`, I have to call it like `foo.default()`. This is not what I want.

I also tried writing it as a standalone file and just doing

```
echo 'export default ' | paste -d'\0' - src.js > module.js
```

It kinda works but I wonder if there are more sophisticated and reliable solutions.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this and created a template repo for this exact task.

You can create your repo from this template, implement your library as a NPM package with ES modules, and then on push the dist folder will be created, and there will be the distributive js file named after your library. Your users can just add it to a script tag and your library will appear at the global namespace.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you might want to package your project as a UMD

https://github.com/umdjs/umd

Rollup can target UMD as output and is a bit more minimal than either webpack or browserify (especially for tiny single function libs)

`isEven.mjs`

```js
function isEven(x) {
  return (x % 2) === 0 && x !== 0;
}

export {
  isEven
};
```

```sh
$ rollup isEven.mjs --format=umd --name=isEven
```

Will result in

```js
(function (global, factory) {
  typeof exports === 'object' && typeof module !== 'undefined' ? factory(exports) :
  typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ? define(['exports'], factory) :
  (global = typeof globalThis !== 'undefined' ? globalThis : global || self, factory(global.isEven = {}));
}(this, (function (exports) { 'use strict';

  function isEven(x) {
    return (x % 2) === 0 && x !== 0;
  }

  exports.isEven = isEven;

  Object.defineProperty(exports, '__esModule', { value: true });

})));
```

Which I think is exactly what you want.

Comment: Good, I didn't knew that! Can I also transform that mjs module to an ES6 module?

Comment: thank you for pointing me towards rollup. I solved this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63746824/making-a-standalone-library-out-of-es-module/63747968#63747968